# What is the relationship between Hölder spaces and differentiability?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fractional-calculus, function-spaces

I'm porting this question over from MSE as it did not get any responses other than one comment on there.

Let $C^{k,\alpha}$ be a Hölder space where $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$. I have seen various sources informally describe these spaces as functions having at least "$k + \alpha$" derivatives. How does some sense of fractional differentiability follow from the definition of the Hölder norm?

Comment: Sobolev embedding embedding theorem. (Rellich-Kondrachov theorem)

Comment: The classic reference for this is chapter 6 of: Adams, Robert A., and John JF Fournier. Sobolev spaces. 1975.

Comment: One thing. $\alpha$ Holder functions are indeed $\beta$ fractional differentiable for all $\beta<\alpha$.

Comment: Doesn’t the definition indicate this?

Comment: @Oxonon, could you explain your comment?

Comment: on a side note, recall that the celebrated example by Weierstrass of a nowhere differentiable continuous function, is actually Hölder, with exponent that I think can be made arbitrarily close to $1$.

Comment: To follow up on @PietroMajer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776879/h%C3%B6lder-continuity-of-weierstrass-function

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/303774/reference-request-interpolation-of-h%C3%B6lder-spaces seems to be relevant to the question asked also.

Comment: @Deane Yang, the requisite differentiability properties all follow from the definition of Sobolev spaces, and the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem, which relates Holder and Sobolev spaces, which may be found in chapter 6 of the Adam's book I cite above.

Comment: @Oxonon, what’s the definition of a function with half a derivative you have in mind?

Comment: @Oxonon Thank you for the reference, I will take a look at it.

Comment: @Oxonon, I looked up Adams’ book. Chapter 6 is about Sobolev spaces with integer orders of derivatives, not fractional. But Chapter 7 looks relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain. The fractional Sobolev space $W^{s,p}(D)$, $0<s<1$, $1<p<\infty$ is defined as the space of all $f\in L^p(D)$ such that
$$
[f]_{s,p}=\left(\int_D\int_D\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{n+sp}}\, dxdy\right)^{1/p}<\infty.
$$
The space is equipped with the norm $\Vert f\Vert_{s,p}=\Vert f\Vert_p+[f]_{s,p}$.

It is easy to prove (by a straightforward estimate of the integral that
$C^{0,\alpha}(D)\subset W^{1-\frac{1}{p},p}(D)$ whenever $1<p<\infty$ and $1-\frac{1}{p}<\alpha\leq 1$. In that sense H"older functions belong to some fractional Sobolev spaces.

You can find some basic facts in

*Di Nezza, Eleonora; Palatucci, Giampiero; Valdinoci, Enrico*, [**Hitchhiker’s guide to the fractional Sobolev spaces**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.bulsci.2011.12.004), Bull. Sci. Math. 136, No. 5, 521-573 (2012). [ZBL1252.46023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1252.46023).

Comment: I still don’t understand why the definition of Holder itself indicates it is a fractional derivative.

Comment: @DeaneYang To discuss fractional derivatives in the setting of $W^{s,p}$ spaces one would have to go through the Fourier transform. While it is relatively elementary when $p=2$, it is more difficult when $p\neq 2$ as it involves singular integrals. This is quite complicated and lengthily overall and I am not going to write about it since it would require me to spend hours refreshing my memory. Sorry for that.

Comment: What I’m trying to ask is why do we have to mention Sobolev spaces at all?

Comment: It is not true that you need to define fractional derivatives through Fourier transform.

Comment: @user479223 Yes and no. The case $n=1$ is somewhat easy. The case when $n>1$ is more delicate. You can define the fractional power of the Laplace operator through an integral formula, but if you want to prove properties of it, you need to use Fourier transform.

Answer (score 4):

Theorem 14 in https://eudml.org/doc/167995 says that if $f\in C^\alpha$ and $\beta<\alpha$ then $D^\beta f$ exists and we have that $D^\beta f\in C^{\alpha-\beta}$, where $D^\beta$ is the fractional derivative.

For example $D^\beta x^\alpha=\operatorname{Const} \cdot x^{\alpha-\beta}$.

See:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685689/does-taking-a-fractional-derivative-remove-a-fractional-amount-of-holder-regular